# Can we reword the Too Localized close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

The close reason for *Too Localized* currently reads as:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

Can we change it a bit so it reads somewhat as follows:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet, *or has been suddenly resolved without explanation.* For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

It currently (IMHO) confuses to not know that the question was closed for suddenly solving itself without explanation, as the close reason ("Too Localized") doesn't directly allude to this, and the long text doesn't directly address this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Comment comment comment comment comment comment comment comment. ;P *Balmer style!*

Answer (score 2):

*Here's my take on this. I'd encourage others to post different answers, especially if you disagree.*

A question that is suddenly solved without explanation should not always be closed.

In particular, if the question is more general, and has general answers, then just because the OP's situation was later resolved (and without explanation) doesn't mean we should close it.

Instead, questions that are suddenly resolved without explanation should *most often* be closed, because they are *most often* too localized, given the current meaning of "too localized."

That is, a question that is resolved suddenly without explanation, in a situation **where that makes it only applicable to the moment in time during which the OP was struggling with the problem**, or in a situation where not knowing what happened means the post won't help anybody outside **the OP's very narrow situation**, should be closed as too localized.

I'm not against rewording the too localized close reason if people are having trouble seeing how this applies. **But I don't think we should reword it in a way that makes it broader than it currently is.** When the OP's *problem* is highly localized but the actual *question* is not, the question should not be closed.